# SQL Server 2008 - Query to return Max Date (including all ties)

Tags: sql-server

I am hoping to write a query to return the max date, based on a few conditions.  Also - I need the flexibility to adjust this date

I have attached a screenshot of the table & columns.

[dbo.MonitoringAnswer Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7bOZ.jpg)

SELECT TOP 1000

```
  ,[ID]
  ,[MT_ID]
  ,[MTA_ID]
  ,[MTDR_ID]
  ,[MTA_DateTime]
  ,[MTA_DateTime_Int]
  ,[MTD_Name]
  ,[USR_Name]
  ,[USR_ID]
  ,[USR_RealID]
  ,[USR_ST_ID]
  ,[CUS_ID]
  ,[CUS_ST_ID]
  ,[CUS_RealID]
  ,[CUS_Name]
  ,[CUS_Addr1]
  ,[CUS_City]
  ,[CUS_CL1_Text]
  ,[CUS_CL1_NAME]
  ,[CUS_CL2_Text]
  ,[CUS_CL2_NAME]
  ,[CUS_CL3_Text]
  ,[CUS_CL3_NAME]
  ,[PRD_ID]
  ,[PRD_ST_ID]
  ,[PRD_RealID]
  ,[PRD_LongName]
  ,[PRC_ID_Name]
  ,[MTDR_Name]
  ,[MTAR_Ans_AsText]
  ,[MTAR_Ans_AsNumber]
  ,[MTAR_Ans_AsDateInt]
  ,[MTAR_Ans_OptionID]
  ,[MTAR_Ans_OptionText]
  ,[MTDR_AnsType_Text]
  ,[MT_ANSWER_PICTURE]
  ,[LinkID]
  ,[PictureLinkToPhoto]
  ,[APP_ID]
  ,[ST_ID]
  ,[ST_Name]
  ,[MTDR_SeqNo]
  ,[DM_LastUpdated]
```

FROM [ca_mars_quoforecloud].[dbo].[MonitoringAnswer]

I need to bring all the columns from the table - the condition is that I need to return only the latest values from Cus_RealID

where max date = 2017xxxx from Mta_DateTime_Int
based on Cus_RealID 
and where frm_id in (xx, xx, xx)

If there is a tie on the MaxDate, I need to be able to return the ties.

In the below screenshot, I have provided an example of sample data - please keep in mind that there are over 300,000 rows in this table.

[SampleData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKWAq.jpg)

ID  MT_ID   MTA_ID  MTDR_ID MTA_DateTime    MTA_DateTime_Int
50002702979 52  5000270 2   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002703977 52  5000270 3   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002708977 52  5000270 8   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002708978 52  5000270 8   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002704978 52  5000270 4   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002706980 52  5000270 6   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002707979 52  5000270 7   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002703979 52  5000270 3   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002707978 52  5000270 7   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002708980 52  5000270 8   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002704977 52  5000270 4   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002704979 52  5000270 4   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002705978 52  5000270 5   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002706977 52  5000270 6   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002707980 52  5000270 7   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002703980 52  5000270 3   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002704980 52  5000270 4   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002703978 52  5000270 3   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002706979 52  5000270 6   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002702980 52  5000270 2   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002706978 52  5000270 6   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002702977 52  5000270 2   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002702978 52  5000270 2   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002705980 52  5000270 5   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002708979 52  5000270 8   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002705977 52  5000270 5   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002707977 52  5000270 7   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002705979 52  5000270 5   10/26/2017 16:04    20171026
50002085977 52  5000208 5   10/4/2017 15:56         20171004
50002082977 52  5000208 2   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002082978 52  5000208 2   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002087977 52  5000208 7   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002083977 52  5000208 3   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002084978 52  5000208 4   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002086977 52  5000208 6   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002086978 52  5000208 6   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002085978 52  5000208 5   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002087978 52  5000208 7   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002083978 52  5000208 3   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002088977 52  5000208 8   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002088978 52  5000208 8   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
50002084977 52  5000208 4   10/4/2017 15:56 20171004
5.00015E+11 33  5000150 12  9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001501977 33  5000150 1   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001503978 33  5000150 3   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
5.00015E+11 33  5000150 11  9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001505978 33  5000150 5   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001501978 33  5000150 1   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
5.00015E+11 33  5000150 12  9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001502977 33  5000150 2   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001506978 33  5000150 6   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001502978 33  5000150 2   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001506977 33  5000150 6   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001503979 33  5000150 3   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001502979 33  5000150 2   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
5.00015E+11 33  5000150 11  9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001505979 33  5000150 5   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001503977 33  5000150 3   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
5.00015E+11 33  5000150 12  9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001505977 33  5000150 5   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
5.00015E+11 33  5000150 11  9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001501979 33  5000150 1   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
50001506979 33  5000150 6   9/13/2017 22:11 20170913
5.00004E+11 33  5000037 11  7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
5.00004E+11 33  5000037 11  7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000376977 33  5000037 6   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000376979 33  5000037 6   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000372978 33  5000037 2   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000375978 33  5000037 5   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000373978 33  5000037 3   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
5.00004E+11 33  5000037 10  7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000376978 33  5000037 6   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000373980 33  5000037 3   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000375980 33  5000037 5   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000375979 33  5000037 5   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000373977 33  5000037 3   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000375977 33  5000037 5   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000371980 33  5000037 1   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000372977 33  5000037 2   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000376980 33  5000037 6   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
5.00004E+11 33  5000037 11  7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000371977 33  5000037 1   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000371979 33  5000037 1   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
5.00004E+11 33  5000037 11  7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000373979 33  5000037 3   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000372979 33  5000037 2   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000372980 33  5000037 2   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
5.00004E+11 33  5000037 10  7/25/2017 13:09 20170725
50000371978 33  5000037 1   7/25/2017 13:09 20170725

What I would expect the query to do in this one example is to return all the results for this particular cus_realid where MTA_DateTime_Int is 20171026 - I don't care about the ones from before this date.

Comment: Please we need `Formatted text` instead of images, edit your question and add table structure, sample data, desired outputs, as formatted text.

Comment: Thanks Sami  - will do.  Sorry about that

Comment: Here is the part that makes no sense "where max date = 2017xxxx from Mta_DateTime_Int based on Cus_RealID and where frm_id in (xx, xx, xx)". We don't have Cus_RealID or frm_id in the sample data and that description makes no sense either way. Then you also state "I need to bring all the columns from the table - the condition is that I need to return only the latest values from Cus_RealID" But your desired output does not seem to have all the columns and there is clarity what you mean by the "latest values".

Comment: If you really want some help what we need to see is a clear definition of the problem. The table structure, data and desired output for the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on:

> What I would expect the query to do in this one example is to return
>   all the results for this particular cus_realid where MTA_DateTime_Int
>   is 20171026 - I don't care about the ones from before this date.

And:

> and where frm_id in (xx, xx, xx)

It sounds like you are just trying to:

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = '10/26/2017'

SELECT *
FROM [ca_mars_quoforecloud].[dbo].[MonitoringAnswer]
WHERE Mta_DateTime_Int=@mydate AND frm_id in (xx, xx, xx)
```

But it's also possible you meant that you just want the last record each Cus_RealID had up to that date.  If a Cus_RealID had a record on 10/24 and NOT on 10/25 or 10/26 then you'd still want that one because it is the most recent.

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = '10/26/2017'

SELECT ma.*
FROM [ca_mars_quoforecloud].[dbo].[MonitoringAnswer] ma 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(Mta_DateTime_Int) MaxDate, Cus_RealID
        FROM [ca_mars_quoforecloud].[dbo].[MonitoringAnswer]
        WHERE Mta_DateTime_Int<=@mydate
        GROUP BY Cus_RealID
    ) x on ma.Cus_RealID=x.Cus_RealID AND ma.Mta_DateTime=x.MaxDate
WHERE frm_id in (xx, xx, xx)
```

For further help you really need to clarify your question.